# Mongodb Shell Update Query

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently getting the following error below when trying to run an update query in MongoDB Shell. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is an error. I've tried all the below combinations of queries, and all give the same error:

```
1) db.users.update({“username”:”jre”3},{ $set : { “email”: "hello@a.com!"}}); 
2) db.users.update({“username”:”jre”3},{ $set : { “email”: "hello@a.com!"}})
3) db.users.update({username:”jre”3},{ $set : { email: "hello@a.com!"}})
4) db.users.update({username:”jre”3},{ $set : { email: "hello@a.com!"}});
```

Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

I have MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3. Any help?

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your quotation marks look suspicious. You have `”` and `"`. Change the first ones to the latter ones.

Comment: Ah, yes, now it works! You were totally right - I replaced the weird looking quotation marks with normal ones and goodbye ugly, unhelpful error message. Thanks!